# centos install / partitioning

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I'm using NOC-PS to remotely install Centos 6.2 via KVM / IPMI.

I'm going to install cPanel as well and they recommend this layout

```
/boot (99MB)
swap (2x server RAM)
/ (remainder)
```

In the o/s install profile within NOC-PS software, it shows as this:

```
part /boot --fstype ext2 --size 250
part pv.01 --size 1 --grow
volgroup vg pv.01
logvol / --vgname=vg --size=1 --grow --fstype ext4 --fsoptions=discard,noatime --name=root
logvol /tmp --vgname=vg --size=1024 --fstype ext4 --fsoptions=discard,noatime --name=tmp
logvol swap --vgname=vg --recommended --name=swap
```

By the time the default partition setup was done installing Centos, I get this

```
[root@server005 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root   532G  907M  504G   1% /
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             243M   28M  202M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp   1008M   34M  924M   4% /tmp
[root@server005 ~]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Dec  7 18:47:24 2012
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg-root     /                       ext4    discard,noatime 1 1
UUID=58b31aaf-5072-4fb1-a858-33bc316fa793 /boot                   ext2    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp      /tmp                    ext4    discard,noatime 1 2
/dev/mapper/vg-swap     swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

My question is, how should the NOC-PS install profile look like to get the recommended cPanel partitioning?

The server has 16GB RAM, dual 600GB SAS drives and will be used for cPanel shared hosting.

Comment: Your installation looks reasonable enough. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I see no swap in df -i output. And then there's the other /tmp and /dev/shm that do not need to be there according to cpanel. http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/InstallationGuide/ConfiguringOs

Comment: The cPanel recommended layout looks odd to me. Part of that is because there are two schools of thought. 1) Use as few partitions as possible. 2) Make a robust setup with separate /tmp, /var/log, /var/log/mail, etc etc. So that one runaway process will not bring down the entire server. For servers I subscribe to belief 2.  For quick test machines (DevOps) 1 will do fine. --- Secondly: Swap twice as big a RAM? That was useful in ye old times. These days that no longer holds.

Comment: I don't see anything in those docs that say that those should be removed. And your swap wouldn't appear in `df` output anyway. Use `free` to see how much swap you currently have active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is reasonable engouh. `/dev/shm` is okay. You can just accept that it is mandatory for any recent Linux installation.

Having `/tmp` on a separate disk is not a bad idea. If you really want to get rid of it, you can take out the line that says `logvol /tmp`. No need to do that, though.

Swap does not show in the output of `df` but you can see it with `free -m` or `cat /proc/swaps`. And "double the size of RAM" is an archaic recommendation that you can probably ignore. You can also refer to [Should I completely turn off swap for linux webserver?](https://serverfault.com/questions/352431/should-i-completely-turn-off-swap-for-linux-webserver/398224#398224) for more discussion on swap.